# jquery remove from dom based on variable

Tags: jquery, dom

Have a script to add / remove options from a select field -- the "value" of the option I want to remove should be equal to the "class" of the link clicked. I've tried several different versions of this script and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to properly get the variable delText into the function to remove it. help pls!

```
   $('a.del').click(function() {
      var delText = $(this).attr('class');
      window.parent.$("select[name='<?php echo $f; ?>']").remove($("<option></option>").text(delText));
   });
```

Comment: What's the `<?php ... ?>` doing inside a jQuery/JS function?

Comment: im passing variables into the script

Comment: You pasted the script from the php file, not the generated html of the page, then?

Comment: It doesn't seem like using the class on the link to identify the `option` is going to work, since you also have the `del` class on there...

Comment: Mixing PHP (or any server-side language) into JavaScript is generally a bad idea and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: It gets you into bad habits.  Keep the server-side and client-side separated and talk to them using ajax if you need to do so.  You'll be happy you did.  Altho, I once was a PHP mixer myself... a long time ago.

Comment: I've worked almost exclusively with php for a while now and I'm only recently start to work with jQuery and I know almost nothing of ajax so I guess maybe that's the next thing to learn, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `value` of the element is equal to the `class` of the link, then do this:

```
$('a.del').click(function() {
  var delText = $(this).attr('class');
  $('option[value=' + delText + ']').remove();
});
```

I'm not sure if that actually jives with what you're trying to do? The `<?php ?>` bit seems really out of place, and the I'm not sure about the `window.parent` bit either.

Comment: 44 seconds... *next time* I'm answering before commenting... =)

Comment: @David Sorry mate, I'll try to type more slowly next time :)

Comment: Ah, no worries; I needed to brush up on my html/js-fu anyway, this is simply an incentive... =D

Comment: i have the script running in an iframe and im using php to pass some variables from the page.

Comment: this works perfect though thanks! it wont let me accept the answer yet though but i will later, promise :-D

Comment: @thomas Thanks, I'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$("select[name='<?php echo $f; ?>'] > option[value=" + delText + "]").detach();
```

To select and detach the option with the specified value that is a child (">" selector) of the named select element.

Answer (score 0):

Select the links via `.del` means that you aren't going to be able to use their class to *also* identify their related `<option/>`.  Maybe you could use `rel` instead (for either value).

```
$('a[rel=del]').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('select[name=<?php echo $f; ?>] option')
        .remove('[value=' + $(this).attr('class') + ']');
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/prH9M/

If you pass in a string to [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), it filters the current set (not its children).  You could also select the option (via [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)) and then just call `remove`, without filtering

```
$('select[name=<?php echo $f; ?>]')
    .find('option[value=' + $(this).attr('class') + ']')
    .remove();
```

Comment: thanks for the example, I've tried doing this but it's not working right -- i'm running this script from an iframe so im adding window.parent. onto the front of your example but I still can't get it to remove the options :-(